# What may be done to control the creation of small files under /udf/tmp when created a new UDF in Apache IoTDB V1.1.1?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have customized a UDF in Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.1. After I ran this UDF, I found that many small files are generated under `/udf/tmp` directory. This may affect the efficiency of server operation, so I want to know what method can control the generation of these small files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These small files should be deleted after running UDF in Apache IoTDB. There may be bugs in earlier versions that will not lead to deletion of these files. Try to upgrade the IoTDB server to Version 1.1.2 and try to execute the server again.